# Cant find project for PackageCompiler

Tags: package, julia, packagecompiler.jl

I am trying to create an executable using PackageCompiler.jl. However, whenever I run the command

```
create_app("src/UnsteadyFlowSolvers.jl","UNSflowCompiled")
```

I keep getting the error

```
ERROR: could not find project at "C:\\Users\\Matthew\\OneDrive - Mississippi State University\\Research\\UNSflow\\Ramesh Live\\src\\UnsteadyFlowSolvers.jl"
```

This is the exact location of the file. For instance:

```
include("src/UnsteadyFlowSolvers.jl") ; UnsteadyFlowSolvers.julia_main()
```

works perfectly fine and generates the exact result I would like the executable to return. The Project.toml file is in the current directory if that matters. I have tried an alternate version of the package where the module file is not located in another directory to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 create_app(package_dir::String, compiled_app::String; kwargs...)

  Compile an app with the source in package_dir to the folder compiled_app.
```

So the first argument to `create_app` is the package folder, not the `.jl` file. I'd suggest a `;cd ..` to get outside your project folder, then

```
create_app("Ramesh Live", "UNSflowCompiled")
```